# calculation program in C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a, b, c;

c = a * b;
printf("a는?: ");
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("b는?: ");
scanf("%d", &b);
printf("%d * %d = %d ", a, b, c);

return 0;
}
```

i made a calculation program . but the result is wrong.

if i put 5,10 in a,b
c should be 50(5*10)
but the result is 0
i used a*b instead of c  . then it was solved. but i want to use c variation.
what is the problem?
should i use double instead of int? please tell me the reason why the problem evoked

Comment: The code is performing the multiplication "before" you ask the user for the numbers. Move `c = a * b;` before the last `printf`

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning `c = a * b` at a point when `a` and `b` doesn't have proper values. You should do this calculation after assigning values to `a` and `b`, otherwise result will be some garbage value.

Right way to do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a, b, c;

printf("a는?: ");
scanf("%d", &a);
printf("b는?: ");
scanf("%d", &b);

c = a * b;
printf("%d * %d = %d ", a, b, c);

return 0;
}
```